# Why can't I FaceTime to a Gmail account from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facetime

I am trying to FaceTime my daughter through her Gmail account from my iPhone and I cannot get it to work. I don't understand why I cannot connect to her mail.

Comment: does your daughter have an iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch, or Mac? FaceTime only works through supported Apple devices. https://www.apple.com/mac/facetime/

Comment: What device from Apple does she use? She can sign into iCloud and let you know her Apple ID as a first step if you don't have that answer yet. Editing that detail into the question will help someone give an exact answer.

Comment: Given the date of the question, this may be relevant: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts5419.

Answer (score 2):

Your daughter needs to make sure her gmail.com address is associated with her iCloud account. From an iPad or iPhone, can you send her an iMessage at that same Gmail account (i.e. does the conversation turn "blue" instead of green)?

Email addresses can be added to FaceTime through iOS Settings or through the preferences in FaceTime.app on a Mac.

People FaceTime me all the time at my Google Apps account, so it's possible.

Answer (score -2):

FaceTime is not implemented in this fashion. FaceTime is an Apple-to-Apple communication platform. From [Apple's FaceTime for Mac troubleshooting page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4185), they list the following devices as supported by FaceTime:

- Macs running Mac OS X Snow Leopard v10.6.6 or later
- iPod touch (4th generation) or later
- iPhone 4 or later
- iPad 2 or later (including iPad mini)

FaceTime is not supported by Google devices or platforms, including GMail.

Comment: True, but your Apple ID is just an email address, which can be from any provider – for instance, my Apple ID is a Gmail address. That's probably what the OP meant.